# Stuck while connecting to a linux machine

Tags: linux, unix, administrator

I am trying to connect to my linux machine using and it kind of connects but the prompt is stuck here,any inputs on what is wrong here?also there was build running that is just stuck...so I tried to open a different session and see this issue,if I do a ctrl+C ,any subsequent command I run gets stuck

```
-bash: /usr2/gnakkala/.bashrc: No such file or directory

^C-bash: /usr/local/projects/l4linux/.bash_l4: Interrupted system call
```

usually i GET the following

```
-bash: /usr2/username/.bashrc: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/projects/l4linux/.bash_l4: No such file or directory
arm-linux-gcc 3.4.4
make 3.81
ADS/RVCT 2.1
Mobilinux 4.1

arm-linux-gcc path: /pkg/asw/compilers/gnu/crosstool/arm-3.4.4/bin
make path: /pkg/gnu/make/3.81/bin
ARM compiler path: /pkg/asw/compilers/arm/RVCT2.1/RVCT/Programs/2.1/328/linux-pentium
Mobilinux path: /pkg/qct/software/montavista/4.1/mobilinux/devkit/arm/v5t_le/bin
```

Comment: using ... what?

Comment: using ssh secure CRT

Comment: .bashrc is optional, not required, so I don't see why you're getting this error in the first place.

Comment: @barmar - I agree that its optional,I edited my original question that shows what I usually get when logged in ...any clues where it is stuck or how to debug/?

Answer (score 0):

If you can log into the machine using a different user, try adding a .bashrc file or change the shell (bash -> sh, for example) for your user.

```
sudo usermod THEUSERNAME -s /bin/sh
```

Comment: I am getting an error sudo: usermod: command not found

Comment: Try `sudo /usr/sbin/usermod username -s /bin/sh`

Comment: getting a new error usermod: user '/bin/sh' does not exist

Comment: If you can execute sudo commands at all, why not create the `.bashrc` file with `sudo nano /home/username/.bashrc` then press `Ctrl+X -> Y` to save it (without contents).

Comment: what does Ctrl+x --> y MEAN?as soon as i do Ctrl+x ..its exiting